# How can I use my Machine Learning trained model in an optimizer to reverse the problem (use as input the target, y, and get the resulting x)?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, python

So, I have used scikit-learn to train a linear regression model on input variables, X, to predict property Y.

Now, I want to be able to define a (min, max) range for Y, and get what are the possible Xs.

My understanding is that I can do this with an optimizer, by using my trained model as an objective function in conjunction with scipy.optimize. However, I don't find any option that I can use to define the desired min,max for Y.

Comment: Your idea is to use a numerical optimization procedure, where you would first use some random values for X, check what Y the model returns, and then iteratively modify the X's to converge to the desired Y model output?

Comment: Yes, I think what you wrote phrases it. The unknown is the X's for a given Y value. Or a given range of Y values.

Comment: If you want to put a bound on the max or min value of Y then you must use an optimization procedure which allows it, such as "L-BFGS-B", if you want to specify how close you want to be to Y while it being "good enough" then you need to set an epsilon/tolerance parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Since you are using a linear regression model, this problem has a closed form solution: you are trying to solve some linear inequalities. No need for optimization.

Comment: This answer would benefit from a bit more exposition. Can you show what you mean using an example, perhaps?